# What does integer cast as pointer mean?

Tags: rust

Given this code:

```rust
let mut a = 5;
let b = &mut a; 
*b = 6;
println!("{:p}",a as *const i32);
```

and output:

```
0x6
```

Comment: Second line of the output represents contents of `a`, not its address.

Comment: "What does integer cast as pointer mean"... This is a very big [open question](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/95228). On the simple side of things, it "just" treats the integer contents as if they were a pointer address.

Comment: In this case this does pretty much nothing; but there are uses to it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The title was edited in, so the issues of pointer provenance probably weren't on OP's mind, but its a good resource to link regardless.

Comment: @kmdreko even if the provenance wasn't in OP's mind, the technical way to put the question is: what is the semantic of cast from integer to pointer. And you cannot answer that question without pointer provenance (or rather, you cannot explain why we don't have a definite answer yet without talking about pointer provenance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying your code to isolate the line you are asking about, we have the following:

```rust
let mut a = 5;
let b = &mut a; 
*b = 6;
println!("{:p}", a as *const i32);
```

Since `b` is assigned to be a mutable reference to `a`, the line `*b = 6` is modifying the value stored in `a` to be `6`.

Casting an integer to a pointer, as is done in `a as *const i32`, is treating that integer value (in this case, `6`) as the address of the pointer. Therefore, `a as *const i32` is creating a pointer to the data stored at `0x6`.

When you print a pointer, as is done in the other lines in your example, it prints the address of the pointer. So, `println!("{:p}", a as *const i32);` prints the address `0x6`, because the value of `a` is used as the address of the pointer created by the cast.

Comment: I'd say rather that the value of `a` is printed in the same style as an address; the value `6` (regardless of how it is displayed) is *not* the address of any of the variables in question.